# How did i disable 1 tab on small screen in react js using ant design

Tags: reactjs, tabs

How did i disable 1 tab on small screen in react js using ant design.
I have 4 tabs on large screen but I need 3 tabs on small screen. How could I do that?
code like this:

```js
import { Tabs } from 'antd';

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">Tab 1</TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" disabled key="2">Tab 2</TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">Tab 3</TabPane>
  </Tabs>,
  mountNode);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I get... you want to dynamically disable the tabs? In that case... You can set the disabled to a variable. More details and I can maybe add some more.

```js
import { Tabs } from 'antd';

const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;
state = {disabled:true}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
    <TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">Tab 1</TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 2" disabled={this.state.disabled} key="2">Tab 2</TabPane>
    <TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">Tab 3</TabPane>
  </Tabs>,
  mountNode);
```